# MSSQL: Msg 4104 in from-clause

Tags: sql-server

I have a table-based function that gets me all Articles of a module.
I would like to use this function in the from-clause as follows

```
select k.ArtNo as baugruppe, g.* 
from anw.artikel k, dbo.getmengenuebersicht (k.ArtNo) g
where k.ArtNo='5000062217'
```

I get the following error

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   The multi-part identifier "k.ArtNo" could not be bound.

and don't have any clue why this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `getmengenuebersicht`  is a table-valued *function*, you should use [`CROSS APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) so that you can reference the columns from `artikel`  when calling it:

```
select k.ArtNo as baugruppe, g.* 
from anw.artikel k cross apply dbo.getmengenuebersicht (k.ArtNo) g
where k.ArtNo='5000062217'
```

And, in general, you shouldn't be [using `,` joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) in your `FROM` clause. ANSI joins were added to the SQL Standard in 1992 - quarter of a *century* ago.